# Confluence with apache 2.4 as Proxy with TLS

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, confluence, http-proxy, mod-proxy

I still got the same error. "Can't check your base URL
There may be a problem with your proxy configuration.". Even after following the [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/can-t-check-base-url-warning-in-confluence-6-1-or-later-884707131.html) and try and error for days. I have a basic VPS with a LetsEncryt-Certificate, an apache2.4 with all necessary enabled mods, still the same error, even 0Auth(built-in in Confluence and Jira) does not work in Combination with Jira on the same Server.

My Configuration for Confluence in /conf/server.xml in Conector:

```
    <Connector
    port="8090"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"
    maxThreads="150"
    minSpareThreads="25"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    enableLookups="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true"
    acceptCount="100"
    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
    proxyName="confluence.<my_domain>.de"
    proxyPort="443"
    secure="true"
    scheme="https"
    />
```

My Apache config for SSL:

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName        confluence.<my_domain>.de
        ServerAlias       www.confleucne.<my_domain>.de

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/synchrony
      RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8090/$1 [P]

      <Proxy *>
          Require all granted
      </Proxy>

      ProxyPass /synchrony http://localhost:8091/synchrony

      <Location /synchrony>
          Require all granted
          RewriteEngine on
          RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
          RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
          RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:8091%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
      </Location>


        ProxyPass         / http://localhost:8090/ nocanon
        ProxyPassReverse  / http://localhost:8090/

        ProxyRequests     Off
        AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule   ^/confluence/(.+) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
        RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_domain>.de/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/<my_domain>.de/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
    </IfModule>
```

Hope that someone has an idea.